# Conserving Labels during Export to CAD in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling, cad

I can export files to cad (i use ArcGIS 10.2), but the converted file does not involve labels,.

Then i tried to use another option, right click to layer name in Table of Contents then click Convert Labels to Annotation then export to cad but still same problem.

The result is a useless vector data without labels, so how can i export a layer to cad with labels?

Comment: Have you got access to [FME](http://www.safe.com/fme/)? That'll do what you ask.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46741/how-to-convert-labels-to-dwg-cad-file. Export To CAD (Conversion) should export annotation feature classes to CAD files as text (but if I remember right only those stored in the geodatabase, not in the map document)

Comment: I haven't gos FME access

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the precise steps that do not work for you, please? I think this is a duplicate of the Q&A linked to by @AlexTereshenkov.